# A little help in understanding Promise() in javascript

Tags: javascript

For curiosity and because I think this can be helpful in the future, I tried to do a very simplistic animation through a Promise() object, trying to figure it out how it would work and understand how to structure it, but I'm a bit unsure of its structure, because there's a function *movingBox* that doesn't get called.

I was based on these references: [Promise | JavaScript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Deferred | Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred#Properties)

This is the code I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #box {
            width: 75px;
            height: 75px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: blueviolet;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
        <script>
            var box = document.getElementById("box");
            var userScreenY = screen["availHeight"];
            var h = 0; // move horizontally to the left
            var v = 0; // move vertically to the bottom
            var pathLength = userScreenY/3;

            var animByTimeout = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

                resolve(movingBox);
            });

            animByTimeout.then(
                function(func) {
                    func();  // here I suppose movingBox should get called 
                    console.log(func);
                }
            ).catch(
                (reason) => {
                    console.log("Error? = " + reason);
                }
            );

            function movingBox () {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (h < pathLength) {
                        h++
                        box.style["left"] = h + "px";

                        if (h >= pathLength/2) {
                            v++;
                            box.style["top"] = v + "px";
                        }

                        movingBox();
                    }
                }, 20);
            };            

            box.addEventListener("click", animByTimeout);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any clearification of what I am doing wrong would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**
I had wrong placed curly braces inside the `.then()` method, I misunderstood the example given in [Advanced Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Examples). This error was pointed out by Wiktor Zychla in the comments. Totally my bad in this point. I already corrected the code above, but to keep track of everything here what was wrong and the corrected way.

**Wrong**

```
animByTimeout.then({ }).catch(...
```

**Correct**

```
animByTimeout.then( ).catch(...
```

Thanks for all examples and helps.

Comment: In you code the usage of a Promise does not make any sense. What it the reason why you want to use a Promise here?

Comment: It looks like you don't need promises at all. Have you tried removing the promise code, and just using `movingBox` as the event listener?

Comment: What do you think `animByTimeout.then({ function(func) { ... } })` does?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, not really sure, but maybe invoke the movingBox() from resolve ? I based on those references-links above.

Comment: @Doug You wrote that piece of code with a certain expected behavior in mind, so you should be able to explain what `animByTimeout.then({ function(func) { ... } })` the in your opinion does/what you want it to do. (even if it is wrong)

Comment: @Doug: point here is that `.then( {function...} )` is wrong, there is no point in having the function as the key in an anonymous object. What you wanted is `.then( function... )`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, I misunderstood the examples. Thanks for the correction. Changing that now I got some result. Now the box moves after reloading the page, but without clicking anywhere, a bit strange because the element is being listened..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the concept of a promise is that you can use the returned method `then()` to perform a callback once the logic inside the function has executed. In your example you execute `resolve()` when you construct the promise. This means your animation will run after the promise resolves. What you want to do is call `resolve()` once your animation loop is done.

I think you were trying to achieve the following,

```
    function movingBox (x, y, distance, element) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        (function animate() {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (x < distance) {
              x++
              element.style["left"] = x + "px";

              if (y >= distance/2) {
                y++;
                element.style["top"] = y + "px";
              }

              animate()
            } else {
              resolve("Animation Complete");
            }
          }, 20);
        })()
      })
    };

    movingBox(0, 0, screen.availHeight / 3, document.getElementById("box"))
        .then(response => {
            console.info(response)
        })
```

Working JSFiddle here buddy. https://jsfiddle.net/stwilz/31w9rhLc/20/.

Also, a saucy little value add for you. One of the powerful things about using promises is that you can then chain your functionality. Like so...

```
    movingBox(0, 0, screen.availHeight / 3, document.getElementById("box"))
        .then(response => {
            console.info('Promise 1')
            return movingBox(0, 0, screen.availHeight * 0.66, document.getElementById("box"))
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.info('Promise 2')
            return movingBox(0, 0, screen.availHeight, document.getElementById("box"))
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.info('Promise 3')
            console.info(response)
        })
```

Comment: This is a well concised example. Beautiful. Although, by mistake I had wrong placed curly braces in the .then() method not allowing my script to work. Pointed out by Wiktor Zichla, I was able to see and fixing that it worked. I'm still thankfull for the time and effort you took for helping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <style>
            #box {
                width: 75px;
                height: 75px;
                position: relative;
                background-color: blueviolet;
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
        <script>
            var box = document.getElementById("box");
            var userScreenY = screen["availHeight"];
            var h = 0; // move horizontally to the left
            var v = 0; // move vertically to the bottom
            var pathLength = userScreenY/3;

            var movingBox = function () {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            if (h < pathLength) {
                                h++
                                box.style["left"] = h + "px";

                                if (h >= pathLength/2) {
                                    v++;
                                    box.style["top"] = v + "px";
                                }

                                movingBox();
                            }
                        }, 20);
            };

            var animByTimeout = function(){
                return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
                    if(movingBox && typeof(movingBox) === 'function' )resolve(movingBox);
                    else reject("animation function not found")
                });
            } 

            animByTimeout()
            .then((animationFunc)=>{
                animationFunc()
            }).catch(
                (reason) => {
                    console.log("Error? = " + reason);
                }
            );


            box.addEventListener("click", animByTimeout);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

although the example you are using completely irrelevant to learn Promise but I think you are trying for this one

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort in helping, Saikat. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: happy coding @Doug

Comment: If you use new features like Promises use also the other new features like let instead of var ;)